# Mulitline code quotation in markdown

Tags: markdown

I am trying to quote several lines of code in the following manner

```
Code line 1
Code line 2
Code line 3
```

However that does not seem to work, as the lines appear as one line in the rendered output. Any ideas?

Comment: Which Markdown implementation are you using? You appear to be trying to use a fenced code block, which is not standard Markdown and not supported by all implementations. However, some implementations offer support as an option you can enable. We'll need more info to help you.

Comment: I am using markdownpad 2 to edit and doxygen 1.8.1.1 to render it. I found what I was missing so I am actually answering my own question below.

Answer (score 1):

> Pre-formatted code blocks are used for writing about programming or
>   markup source code. Rather than forming normal paragraphs, the lines
>   of a code block are interpreted literally. Markdown wraps a code block
>   in both `<pre>` and `<code>` tags.
>
> To produce a code block in Markdown, simply indent every line of the
>   block by at least 4 spaces or 1 tab.

— https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode

```
This is a Markdown code block:

    Code line 1
    Code line 2
    Code line 3
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question. Code blocks are added by putting at east 4 **extra** spaces in the beginning of the line. So if the current paragraph has an indentation of 4 (because it is part of a bullet list for example) then **8** spaces must be added in the beginning of the line.